# How can I extract the title of a pdf when downloading them?

Tags: pdf, web, scripting

I deal with pdfs a lot but when I try to download them it usually doesn't contain the actual title of the pdf/paper so I'll have to rename it most of the times, which I find is annoying.

In many cases URL doesn't have the title of the pdf, so I guess this has to be extracted by processing the content of the pdf. And it needs to be done on the client side, i.e., for e.g., as a browser plugin?
 Is there a way that I can get the title when I'm downloading pdfs over the web via scripting or someting?

Answer (score 0):

That most likely won't work and here is why.

1. You would have to write some incredibly dynamic code to fetch some sort of title for the PDF.  You would have to have code that would scan a website, somehow pick out a title, then fire off a request to code running on your computer to change the name.
2. It would be somewhat inconvenient because you would always have to have the script run on your computer (likely always having terminal open).
3. Your code would be highly prone to error.  If your website script messed up, you could accidentally name the PDF incorrectly and then not be able to find it based on how inaccurate the name is.

For now, I would suggest dealing with the pain of editing the PDF name manually.